# How to setup CiviCRM for multiple simultaneous telefundraisers?

Tags: fundraising

We are using CiviCRM for telefundraising. Basically, we have a list of contacts to call (smart group). After each call, the fundraiser registers a phone call activity in CiviCRM. When the activity is registered, the contact is temporarily removed from the group (using include/exclude search).

How can we setup the system so that different fundraisers are not messing with each other and avoid simultaneously calling the same contacts? Preferably, in long term we would like the same fundraisers to call the same contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of

- grab some contacts
- bulk create Activities for them all (one per each) with the person you want to make those calls as the Assignee
- set them up with some Reports (or Drupal Views linked to webforms) that will show each person what Calls are in what Status

Note you may want to create a custom Activity Type with a custom field for the outcome of call (eg busy so callback, etc) and use that field data in combination with the Activity Status to ensure that you have a useful record of which people need trying again etc.

We have worked on developing something along those lines but with more sophistication using Views and Webforms but is only relevant to Drupal installs. This also allowed for folk to 'self-assign' more calls from the pool if they had done their allocation.

There is also the CiviEngage package that comes with the drupal install which you can read about here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/civic-engagement/what-is-civiengage/

Comment: We also had a block on the Callers 'My Calls' screen so they could just 'assign me 3 more' button which would give them a few more to go on with. of course that could be finessed i guess to the '3' could be a selectable value, but for that client (back then) it worked nicely

Comment: Is it a custom code or available as open source?

Comment: it is a bunch of Views and Webforms, with a bit of custom for the 'add 3 more' but none of it has been 'packaged' up

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [CiviRules](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviRules+Cookbook). This extension gives you the option to automatically remove a contact from a group when an activity of a particular type is created. So you can define a group *Call Backlog*, instruct your fundraisers to select any contact that is in this group. When they log a *Call* activity the contact is removed from the group, so the other callers will not select it.

Comment: Still potential for someone else to pick that person up during the duration of the call that the other fundraiser is currently making?